# I have a multi lined output and I need to split and push the data into arrays

Tags: perl, split, dynamic-arrays

I have an output which has similar lines with unique data. I have to cut the unique data into different arrays and use it in a forloop. Also, my output would not have a fixed number of lines and depends on time of execution when kept in cron job.

For example:

```
Thestudentname=ravi&class=2&availbus=yes&city=hyd
Thestudentname=shyam&class=4&availbus=no&city=cal
Thestudentname=rohan&class=6&availbus=yes&city=mum
.
.
.
```

Here names, class, bus and city should be my arrays and all of them have same number of array elements for a given execution.

Comment: Hi Arpita, please show us your effort to solve your problem? Also your question is not very clear `cut the unique data into different arrays` here. Please show us your expected output also.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( @names, @classes, @buses, @cities );

while (<DATA>) {    # loop over lines; line is stored in $_
    my ( $name, $class, $bus, $city ) =
      /Thestudentname=(\w+)&class=(\d+)&availbus=(\w+)&city=(\w+)/;
    push @names,   $name;
    push @classes, $class;
    push @buses,   $bus;
    push @cities,  $city;
}

# Print out the arrays' content
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \( @names, @classes, @buses, @cities );

__DATA__
Thestudentname=ravi&class=2&availbus=yes&city=hyd
Thestudentname=shyam&class=4&availbus=no&city=cal
Thestudentname=rohan&class=6&availbus=yes&city=mum
```